# Find the count and sum of different columns across multiple tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 separate tables as below:

The real world scenario has many other columns, but these will suffice.

Main:

| id | total_task |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

Task that has a foreign key on the main table:

| t_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| t1 | 1 |
| t2 | 2 |
| t3 | 2 |
| t4 | 3 |
| t5 | 3 |
| t6 | 3 |

And finally an Error table that will log any failed tasks that has a foreign key on the task table above.

| e_id | t_id | error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | t1 | error |
| e2 | t2 | new error |
| e3 | t3 | error |
| e4 | t4 | something |

I need the resulting output from the query to be as follows:

| error | main count | error count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| error | 3 | 2 |
| new error | 2 | 1 |
| something | 3 | 1 |

Basically I want to group the error messages, count the occurrence of the error message and also retrieve the sum of the total_task that is in the main table if the same error message occurred across multiple main IDs.

So far, I'm unable to retrieve the total count as a sum. I've tried using partitions, multiple CDEs etc but I'm unsure how to link the tables together to achieve this. While I understand that I could join the tables on id, t_id and e_id, I can't seem to find a way to get the sum.

Is there a way to retrieve the data in the way I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your goal in 2 parts:

1. Get error_count per error
2. Get main_count per error

The first query is trivial:

```
select error, count(*) from Error group by error
```

For the second query you need to:

1. Get main id occurrences per error
2. Sum their total_task

```
select error, sum(total_task) as main_count from (
  select distinct error, id from Error join Task using (t_id)
) as subquery
group by error
```

To end up with one table, you can join the 2 queries `using (error)`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something like this in the end and it worked.